# Use composite index or index merge to support searching variable columns?

Tags: mysql, index

I'm trying to understand how to best add indexes to the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ideas (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idea TEXT NOT NULL,
    age_range VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    county VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    category VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    subcategory VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    language_choice VARCHAR(30) NULL
    entry_date DATETIME,
);
```

I've already added a fulltext index on `idea`:

```
ALTER TABLE ideas ADD FULLTEXT (idea);
```

I need the table to support searches across different combinations of columns, e.g.

```
WHERE language_choice = 'English' AND county IN ('foo', 'bar') AND MATCH(`idea`) AGAINST('baz')

WHERE language_choice = 'English' AND county = 'foo' AND age_range = 'bar'

WHERE language_choice = 'English' AND category = 'foo' AND age_range = 'bar' AND MATCH(`idea`) AGAINST('baz')
```

... basically, any combination of the VARCHAR columns and the idea column, with possible multiple search values specified for each.

The `language_choice` column contains the fewest distinct values, and will be specified in all queries.

I think my options here are to either create a composite index, or create multiple single indexes on the VARCHAR columns and let mysql merge them. Is this correct? What's recommended? Is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

```
FULLTEXT(category, country, idea)

SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(category, country, idea) AGAINST("string")
```

That is, lump all string columns together in a single fulltext index and apply the search against that.

Fulltext has limitations on minimum word length, "stop" words, punctuation, etc.  Notice that I did not include "age_range" for fear that that involves numbers and/or "<" and ">".  If, instead, "age_range" is "child/teen/adult/senior", then it could be treated as a string and included in the Fulltext technique.

Now, to address your ideas:

```
WHERE language_choice = 'English'
  AND county IN ('foo', 'bar')
  AND MATCH(`idea`) AGAINST('baz')
```

The FULLTEXT search will be done first; indexes on the other columns won't matter.

```
WHERE language_choice = 'English'
  AND county = 'foo'
  AND age_range = 'bar'
```

That would benefit from this composite index; the order of the columns won't matter (since all the tests are simply "="):  `INDEX(language_choice, country, age_range)`

```
WHERE language_choice = 'English'
  AND category = 'foo'
  AND age_range = 'bar'
  AND MATCH(`idea`) AGAINST('baz')
```

Again, the FULLTEXT takes precedence.

More `AND` cases:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see what is going on.  I would be excited to see any cases you turn up where "Index merge...Intersect" is used.  Especially if Fulltext is included.  When "Intersect" (without Fulltext), it almost certainly indicates that a composite index would be better.

`OR` and "Index merge...Union" is a different kettle of fish.